# Use COUNTIFS count values for specific range of the results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

To simplify my ultimate problem, let's just say I have a column called RESULT that can have the values WIN or LOSS and another column called LEAGUE that can have the values NBA, NFL, MLB, NHL. I want to count the number of WINs that appear in the 100-200 results of NBA. Is there a way to do this using COUNTIFS or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's easily done, but here is one of doing it using an array formula:
`=COUNTIFS(OFFSET(A$1,0,0,SMALL(IF("NBA"=$A:$A,ROW($A:$A)),100),1),"NBA",OFFSET(B$1,0,0,SMALL(IF("NBA"=$A:$A,ROW($A:$A)),100),1),"WIN")`
Or:
`=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("A1:A"&SMALL(IF("NBA"=$A:$A,ROW($A:$A)),100)),"NBA",INDIRECT("B1:B"&SMALL(IF("NBA"=$A:$A,ROW($A:$A)),100)),"WIN")`

- You need to complete the formula by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> which will add `{` and `}` around the formula (*adding it manually won't do anything, it needs to be added by pressing the mentioned shortcut*)
- Change the two mentions of `100` to the amount of `NBA` rows you want to count

To get the count inside a specific from-to (i.e. count the WINs in the 101-200 NBA rows from within the other rows) you can do something like this:
`=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("A"&SMALL(IF("NBA"=$A:$A,ROW($A:$A)),101)&":A"&SMALL(IF("NBA"=$A:$A,ROW($A:$A)),200)),"NBA",INDIRECT("B"&SMALL(IF("NBA"=$A:$A,ROW($A:$A)),101)&":B"&SMALL(IF("NBA"=$A:$A,ROW($A:$A)),200)),"WIN")`

- Also with the same <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> since it's an array formula
- Change the two mentions of `101` to the beginning number of `NBA` rows you want to count, and the two `200` to the end number

Comment: Yeah it's that except specifying a specific range of the values returned from your query above, like the first 100, or 101-200.

Comment: So from the first 100 rows that have NBA in `A` you want to count how much of them are WIN?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Is that possible?

Comment: Not easily. I edited my answer, see if this helps

Comment: Thanks so much for that.